# Why can't I add onload event listener to body element using addEventListener method

Tags: dom

add unload event listener this is works
    
but

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>  
    </body>
        <script>
            function give_show(value){
                return function(){
                console.log(value);
                }
            }
            var body_element = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
            body_element.addEventListener('load',give_show('pong!'),false)
        </script>
</html>
```

Comment: put the script in the `head` before `body`

Answer (score 0):

The `body` has already loaded before the event is attached. Try moving the script to the `<head>` tag and using:

```
<body onload="give_show('pong!')">
```